# How to avoid the repeated paragraghs of long txt files being ignored for importdata in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import all double from a txt file, which has this form

```
#25x1 string

#9999x2 double
.
.
.

#(repeat ten times)
```

However, when I am trying to use import Wizard, only the first

```
25x1 string
9999x2 double.
```

was successfully loaded, the other 9 were simply ignored

How may I import all the data? (Does importdata has a maximum length or something?) 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with maximum length, `importdata` is just not set up for the sort of data file you describe. From the help file:

> For ASCII files and spreadsheets, importdata expects
>   to find numeric data in a rectangular form (that is, like a matrix).
>   Text headers can appear above or to the left of the numeric data,
>   as follows:
>
> Column headers or file description text at the top of the file, above
>   the numeric data.  Row headers to the left of the numeric data.

So what is happening is that the first section of your file, which does match the format `importdata` expects, is being read, and the rest ignored.  Instead of `importdata`, you'll need to use `textscan`, in particular, this style:

```
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N)
```

`fileID` is returned from `fopen`.  `formatspec` tells `textscan` what to expect, and N how many times to repeat it.  As long as `fileID` remains open, repeated calls to `textscan` continue to read the file from wherever the last read action stopped - rather than going back to the start of the file.  So we can do this:

```
fileID = fopen('myfile.txt');
repeats = 10;

for n = 1:repeats

    % read one string, 25 times
    C{n,1} = textscan(fileID,'%s',25); 
    % read two floats, 9999 times
    C{n,2} = textscan(fileID,'%f %f',9999);

end
```

You can then extract your numerical data out of the cell array (if you need it in one block you may want to try using `'CollectOutput',1` as an option).

Comment: The import Wizard suggested 25x1(each line considered as 1), however, when i am using textscan, it acquires word by word rather than line by line. So instead of reading the first 25 lines. it acquires the first 25 words and stopped to read double. How can I tell matlab not to do that? Thanks

Comment: You need a format string which is '%s' repeated 25 times, and N = 1, in that case (you can use `repmat`, rather than just writing it out).

Comment: I  changed it into % read one string, 25 times
    C{n,1} = textscan(fileID,'%s',25,'Delimiter','\r'); and its working now. Thanks again!